# Objects filtered by ManyToManyField_in do not contain the rest of ManyToMany field values, how to get them?

Tags: django, filter, models, manytomanyfield

I've been trying to find an answer to my question for a while, but can't find exactly what I need.

I've recently started messing with Django(I have searched the docs), which was going fine until now. I'm making a simple gallery app, the idea is simple, each image has a bunch of tags. I want to build a list of tags(no problem there), then selecting a tag - get a list of related tags across all images - there I have a problem, have a look at my view code:

```
def getTagList(request):
    images = Image.objects.all()
    imgsWithTag = images.filter(tags__name__in=["space"]).only('tags')
    allTags = imgsWithTag.values_list('tags__name', flat=True)
```

Here it is - I expected **allTags** to be a list of all the image tags (including 'space' as in example) - instead I get:

```
[u'space', u'space']
```

for the two images I have in my DB. Each image containing two tags ('space' being the common one), but only the 'matched' tag got returned so to speak as far as I understand.

What exactly is happening here & how to avoid it? Is there a better way to do what I'm trying to?

my models are as follows:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60, primary_key=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Image(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/")
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True)
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)

    def thumbnail(self):
        return '<img src="%s" height="40" />' % (self.image.url)
    thumbnail.short_description = 'Image'
    thumbnail.allow_tags = True

    def get_tags(self):
        return ", ".join([x.name for x in self.tags.all()])

    def url(self):
        return self.image.url

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal behavior, because under the hood django is making SQL query with `JOIN`.

To get all related tags you can use this (assuming: your tag model is named `Tag` and related_name for `ManyToMany` joining images with tags is `images`:

```
def getTagList(request):
    images = Image.objects.all()
    imgsWithTag = images.filter(tags__name__in=["space"])
    allTags = Tag.objects.filter(images__in=imgsWithTag).values_list('tags__name', flat=True)
```

At first it looks like django will do 2 queries: one to get all images and then second to get all tags associated with that images, but that's not the case.

Django is smart enough to join that queries together, so in result you will get one query with nested select on `WHERE`. So you will hit database only once. If you want it to be called twice (sometimes it's better), you can do:

```
def getTagList(request):
    images = Image.objects.all()
    imgsWithTag = images.filter(tags__name__in=["space"]).values_list('id', flat=True)
    allTags = Tag.objects.filter(images__id__in=imgsWithTag).values_list('tags__name', flat=True)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I do not have a field associating each tag with a list of images - that idea just doesn't sound right to me. The Id approach won't work in that case also.

Comment: Yes, you have unless you've specified `related_name='+'` in ManyToMany field linking Image with Tag. Look at [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField.related_name)